# Expectation value of $r^{-3}$ for $\ell=0$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, singularities, hydrogen, orbitals

I'm trying to calculate the hyperfine structure energy for Hydrogen. From Jackson's Electrodynamics book eq. 5.73 we have:

$$H_{HFS}=\dfrac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\left[\dfrac{-8\pi}{3}\mu_{N}.\mu_{e}\delta(r)+\dfrac{1}{r^3}\left(\mu_{N}.\mu_{e}-3\dfrac{(r.\mu_{N})(r.\mu_{e})}{r^2}\right)\right]$$

Which is the Hamiltonian for hyperfine structure. $\mu_{N}$ is the magnetic moment of the nucleus and $\mu_{e}$ is the magnetic moment of the electron.

It can be shown that the expectation value of $\dfrac{1}{r^3}$ is not well defined for the ground state ($n=\ell=0$). Despite this, how do we treat the terms in the square brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angular part of the integral vanishes for $\ell = 0$. (The proof is left as an exercise to the reader;  it helps to choose coordinates such that $\vec{\mu}_N = \mu_N \hat{z}$ and $\vec{\mu}_e = \mu_e (\cos \alpha \hat{z} + \sin \alpha \hat{x})$.)

So if we "do the angular integral first", the expectation value of the second term is zero, and there's no problem.  This is not a 100% legal mathematical move, but it can be justified by noting that the dipole-dipole interaction is for idealized point dipoles.  Since the nuclear dipole (at least) is not an idealized dipole, the interaction term does not truly diverge as $r \to 0$ anyhow, and the "true" interaction term would have a finite radial integral.